# Pass destination node as a string to agent parameter

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to pass the destination node in which my agent is going to/is at as a string.

I have an agent (car) that has multiple parameters one of them being location. I have a resourcePool with multiple home locations in which the car can park (move to home of seized unit). I am trying to collect the node in which the car is parked at and pass it as a string to this location parameter as such when it exits the moveTo block:

```java
if(moveTo.destinationNode(agent) == nodeA) {
    agent.location = "A";
} else {
    agent.location = "NULL";
}
```

However, when a car is parked on nodeA. I expect the value of location to be A, but the parameter comes up as NULL which it should not be. Any recommendation would be of great value. Thanks!

Comment: What is `nodeA`? A `String`?

Comment: nodeA is a INode or pointnode

Comment: If it isn't a primitive, then use `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have used the `==` operator, but you have not overloaded it to compare two nodes. (I don't know how to do this, but you can). Maybe you can do something like `if (x.location == y.location) {}` (I'm making up these names). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to use moveTo.destinationNode(agent).equals(nodeA) instead? Or something simmilar?

Comment: Yes, if they are Strings (I think).

Answer (score 0):

## Issue Fixed:

```
if(agent.getNetworkNode() == nodeA){
   agent.location = "A"
} else if(agent.getNetworkNode() == nodeB){
   agent.location = "B"
}
```

... and so on